# Index Out of Bounds Error

Tags: java

I'm running a simple java program. I programmed it in Netbeans. Everything worked great. Attempted to transition code to use Ant because that's what my class requires, and I'm getting a weird error.

All text coming in from the .txt is in the format,

```
Baker William Chavez 04/01/05
Sanchez Jose Chavez 06/15/05
etc ...
```

There about 20 entries, 3 names and a date. Each entry is on its own line.

I'm using this code to read it in.

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    //formatting data correctly
    String [] info = line.split(" ");
    for(int i = 0; i < info.length; i++){
        System.out.println(info[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(info[0]);
    System.out.println(info[1]); /* this line of code */
}
```

So every info [] is of length 4. When I run the for loop, it prints out everything exactly as expected. Printing out "info[0]" works exactly has expected.

But for some reason when I attempt to print out "info[1]", I get an

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

error. I have no explanation for why this happens. When I don't attempt to print out info[1] by itself, my program works correctly. In the for loop, info[1] gets printed out, because the for loop loops through 4 times. This code worked perfectly in Netbeans, but using Ant is doesn't work.

Does anyone know adding or removing just one line,

```
System.out.println(info[1]);
```

causes my program to run or throw an exception?

I'm running Ant 1.9.2

I'm running Java 1.7.0_17

I've checked this multiple times, so I'm pretty sure its not something I've made an erro ron. I'm a fairly experienced programmer, so I pretty confident it's not my error. It runs well in Netbeans. I don't have an explanation for the error.

edit 1.
My code throws an error the second time threw the while loop.
Printing out the info[] length, or the line itself works great with I don't print out line[1] by itself. It stills fails and throws an error when I printout the info[1] by itself.

http://pastebin.com/NAUeDsZH

Edit 2. 
@Millie Smith was on the right trail because my .txt file wasn't correctly formatted. Viewing it in notepad for some reason didn't display the extra space in between each line. 
http://pastebin.com/njjdSHHZ
My correct pastebin.
I was attempting to use code to strip out all of the blank space, commas, new lines, and such,

```
line = line.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
line = line.replaceAll(",","");
line = line.replaceAll("\\n", "");
line = line.replaceAll("\\r", "");
String [] info = line.split(" ");
```

I incorrectly assumed that that code would take care of any irregularities. I was wrong. So on my first pastebin, I formatted the code to what I thought I was dealing with, which was also incorrect.

So if I test for line.length() > 1, that gives me my results that I am looking for. I'm not an experienced programmer as I think I am.

Comment: Experience != not my error. Println info.length right after the loop... System.out.println("length: " + info.length);

Comment: before calling split add: System.out.println("line = " + line);

Comment: Give us the input file. It sounds like there's an empty line in between each record of data or something. Perhaps pastebin it, but make sure to pastebin *all* of it.

Comment: Uh, you're an getting index out of bounds error because the index is out of bounds.  Check info.length.

Comment: Using your code (except for the initialization) and your pastebin, I have this: http://pastebin.com/hFSykSvn. That works. You're not showing us something.

Comment: @Millie Smith You're right. Give me a minute to explain it.

Comment: *The trouble with ignorance is that it picks up confidence as it goes along.* - Arnold H. Glasow

Comment: In this situation, its better to check if the line is whitespace. Next time don't make assumptions and give everything you can because we can solve the question quicker that way. Thanks. Everyone makes mistakes that aren't the IDEs fault, no matter how professional. Operating systems are littered with zero day exploit bugs, and a guy I know in the industry tried to cast an object to an int the other day.

Answer (score 3):

Your last line of the file is `BLANK` ( probably just a end of line marker ) and this is causing the last `.split(" ")` to assign a single element array with nothing in it but an empty string in the first position.

Make sure your file doesn't have a ZERO length line as the last line or any of the lines.

Learn to use the step debugger, it is your best friend, and step through the code and see what `line` is equal to on the very last iteration.

*Ant and Netbeans have nothing to do with this error, it is completely data related and we can't see your entire data file in its native format*

Comment: The last line was blank. I corrected it. I still throws that error. I forgot to mention that the error is thrown the second time threw the while loop. Not at then end or beginning.

Comment: @MorganK - That's probably because the first time through you get more than one element in info.  Think!!  (Hint:  Put a println of `line` right after the `while`.)

Comment: @MorganK - And don't just do `System.out.println(line);`.  Do `System.out.println("line ==>" + line + "<==");` so you can be sure you're printing `line` and you know how long it is and whether there's any leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson - Is there a step by step debugger in Ant?

Comment: Ant is a build tool and a 20+ year old one at that; there are much better ways to build applications in Java. Maven is a much better choice. Others will argue Gradle. Either way you won't find anyone sane that will argue that Ant is the right way to do things anymore.